# How does WallpaperEngine set the wallpaper in Windows?

Tags: windows, video, wallpaper

The app WallpaperEngine can somehow set the Wallpaper to a HTML page, scene or video. I'm trying to do pretty much the same thing, so I looked and found this option in VLC to set a video as a wallpaper:

[image]

But that just creates a window and not an actual wallpaper. You can see this in the Desktop switcher:

[image]

The WallpaperEngine background (the purple one with the pink blob in the screenshot that you can see on Desktop 2 and 3 and in the background) behaves like a regular wallpaper (but animated). How do they achieve this? Is there some hidden API that allows setting a video stream as a wallpaper or do they just set the wallpaper to that every few milliseconds?

Comment: What does "actually registered as a wallpaper" mean? How can you back up this claim? I bet they are using a window.

Comment: @Anders it looks and behaves like a wallpaper (changed the wording on that in the Q, "registered" is the wrong term there), anywhere you look for a wallpaper, for example the desktop switcher in the screenshot, it shows the wallpaper. The purple one on Desktop 1-3 is WallpaperEngine, that moves if I move my mouse. And they might use some kind of fullscreen window or something to achieve that, but that's what I'm trying to figure out lol

Comment: Have you tried Spy++? Have you looked to see if dwm.exe has injected 3rd-party dlls?

Comment: System requirements on Steam: "Aero must be enabled on Windows 7." This might be a hint that it is DWM related.

Comment: https://help.wallpaperengine.io/en/performance/dwm.html# "... they are part of the Windows Explorer process."